# AppContainer Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#

I have entered this code in my Program.cs file.

```
AppContainer container = new AppContainer();
```

But when I try to debug it, it shows like this.

[image]

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Use nuget to install Win32Interop.User32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Win32Interop.User32/) to include the dependency for you.

Alternatively you could [import the DLL manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-5.0) using `[DllImport("Win32Interop.User32")`.

Here's an excerpt from MSDN showing how to manually import and define methods to use from an imported DLL

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Example
{
    // Use DllImport to import the Win32 MessageBox function.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
    
    static void Main()
    {
        // Call the MessageBox function using platform invoke.
        MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Hello World!", "Hello Dialog", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: But which class should I put it in?

Comment: You would define it in whatever class creates the `AppContainer`. I added a short example from MSDN that might provide some context. Be sure to try the nuget package first though, as manually using DLLs with interop can become exhausting quickly.